# При попытке найти данные в базе данных возникает ошибка

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, phpmyadmin, redbeanphp

В общем у меня есть файл main.py

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'libs/rb.php';
R::setup( 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=rampl','root', '' );
$log_current_user_login = $_SESSION["logged_user"];
if(empty($log_current_user_login)){
  header( "Location: /index.php" );
}else{
  $current_database_data = R::findOne('users1', 'login = ?', [$log_current_user_login]);
}
?>
```

Код ошибки:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class __PHP_Incomplete_Class could not be converted to string in C:\OpenServer\domains\northhp\libs\rb.php on line 5545
```

Как я понял ошибка появляется из-за того, что не возможно привести тип переменной к строковой.
На других сайтах говорили что надо почистить кеш и  куку браузера, но у меня это не сработало.
У меня RedBeanPhp 5.7.1
Локальный сервер Open Server
браузер Chrome
Заранее благодарю за помощь
P.S: Сама ошибка в строке:

```
$current_database_data = R::findOne('users1', 'login = ?', [$log_current_user_login]);
```

Если я заменю эту строку на к примеру существующий логин в базе данных, то все будет работать.

```
$current_database_data = R::findOne('users1', 'login = ?', ['some login']);
```

Comment: файл  rb.php что это за файл, откуда?

Comment: Файл rb.php это фреймворк для php, типо замена sql(sqlиньекции). Скачал с официального сайта https://redbeanphp.com/index.php.